# Not able to authenticate jenkins using cloudbees account

Tags: cloudbees

I created a cloudbees account with my Gmail.

I installed Cloudbees Registration plugin in my jenkins and created a new credentials in jenkins using cloudbees account.

After creating, I am seeing CloudBees Status in Jenkins UI (left bottom of the page) as 'Communication status:  error'

What am I missing here?